# vue.js: how to update state with object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vuejs2

I am a newcomer to vue.js, but I have some experience with React from before.

I have read the vue guidelines and I am trying to understand vue through the concepts from React.

I assume that the vue `data` is similar to the React `state`, since when it updates the app it will render the page again.

So I would like to do something like ... (the code is in React)

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { key1: 'value1', key2 : 'value2'}))
```

But as far as I know, in vue:

```
this.key1 = 'value1';
this.key2 = 'value2';
```

Is that correct? I guess vue will render twice since it is 2 statements.
How could I set multi values at once?

I have already tried ...

```
// not working
this.$set(Object.assign({}, thisRef.data, { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }))

// not working
this.data = { key1 : 'value1', key2: 'value2' };
```

In the second one, data has changed - I have printed value with `console.log(this)`- , but it does not render again.

FYI, the full code from the vue template is here. Code review and correction will be very welcomed.

```
<script>
    export default {
        layout: 'reactQuickly'
        , data: function(){
            return {
                time: null
                , init: null
            }
        }
        , methods: {
            startTimer: function(time){
                clearInterval(this.init);
                let thisRef = this;
                let interval = setInterval(
                    function(){
                    console.log('2: Inside of interval', time)
                    let timeLeft = thisRef.time - 1;
                    if(timeLeft <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
                    thisRef.time = timeLeft;
                    // thisRef.$set(Object.assign({}, thisRef.data, { time: timeLeft }))
                    console.log('thisRef', thisRef, this);}
                , 1000);
                console.log('1: After interval');
                // this.data = { time : time, init: interval };
                this.time = time;
                this.init = interval;
                console.log('this.data', this.data);
                // this.$set(Object.assign({}, this.data, { time : time, init: interval}));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

============ Edition ===========

react `this.state` and vue `this.data` is not same, right?
To me, main confusion starts from that point.

In vue

```
export default {
  data : function() {
    return {
      foo : 'bar'
    }
  }
}
```

and

In react

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    foo : 'bar'
  }
}
```

are completely different concept, right?

Comment: you are able to get/set `time` and ` init` right but not data directly ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Your concern in the question is not necessary. You don't need to worry about `set multi values at once` in Vue.*

(I learnt what I am going to say from this awesome article => [Updating UIs: value comparison VS mutation tracking](https://itnext.io/updating-uis-value-comparison-vs-mutation-tracking-9f6fe912dd9a).)

***React and Vue has very different way of tracking when UI should be updated.***

**React uses Object Immutability.** That's why everytime you `setState`, you essentially are creating a completely new object and the entire component rerender based on the new object values.

[**Vue uses getters/setters on the data object for mutation tracking.**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) When you execute `this.key1 = 'value1';`, it will go through the `setter` of `key1`. In the setter, there's a function to notify the `watcher` and add this data changes to a queue.

> In case you haven’t noticed yet, Vue performs DOM updates
> asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a
> queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event
> loop. If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be
> pushed into the queue only once. This buffered de-duplication is
> important in avoiding unnecessary calculations and DOM manipulations.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Therefore, when you execute `this.key1 = 'value1'; this.key2 = 'value2';`, **it won't render twice.** Vue automatically queues up the data changes and rerender them together later on.

What I meant to say is, your concern in the question is not necessary. You don't need to worry about `set multi values at once` in Vue. React and Vue has very different reactivity system. You might wanna read through the links above to get a better understanding.

(Btw, Vue uses getter/setter now but it will use JS proxy in the future. https://github.com/vuejs/roadmap)

Answer (score 6):

With $set method you can add only one property:

```
this.$set(this.existingObject, 'newProperty', 'value')
```

If you need to add multiple reactive properties, use assign method:

```
this.existingObject = Object.assign({}, this.existingObject, {
  newProperty1: 'value',
  newProperty2: 22
}
```

This is also useful when you want to change just some properties in object, without touching the rest of properties. So:

```
this.existingObject = Object.assign({}, this.existingObject, {
  existingProperty2: 'newValue',
  existingProperty6: 66
}
```

And if you are using Babel, and I assume you do, for both cases, adding or  modifying some props, you can use latest spread feature:

```
let newOrExistingProps = {
  newProperty: 'value',
  existingProperty: 66
}

this.existingObject = {...this.existingObject, ...newOrExistingProps}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got another question. I still compare to react concept - Now I know how those two are different, but it is easier to understand for me -, we change `this.state` in react, is there same keyword like `state` in vue.js? In your answer, you used `this.existingObject` and the term `existingObject` is defined by you, right? If I write `this.data`, is It means `state` of vue object?

Answer (score 0):

**Vuex Store: store.js**

```
 export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    numCorrect: 0, 
    numIncorrect: 0
  }, 
  mutations: {
    increment (state,payload) {
        state.numCorrect = payload.correct;
        state.numIncorrect = payload.incorrect;
      }
  }
});
```

**Vue file: hello.vue**

```
import store from '../store/store'

  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    updateText() {
      store.commit("increment", {correct:4,incorrect: 6 })
    }
  }
});
```